# OpenCV cv::ORB::ScoreType error in OpenCV 4.5.3

Tags: opencv, package, ros, orb

I am using a package where they use the FAST feature detector. I had previously installed OpenCV 3.3.1. I installed OpenCV 4.5.3 together with that. I made sure this package uses the newest version of OpenCV. However I get this error;

/home/didula/BVLOAM_ws/src/visual_odometry/src/image_util.cpp:56:7: error: ‘ScoreType’ is not a member of ‘cv::ORB’
cv::ORB::ScoreType scoreType = cv::ORB::FAST_SCORE;
^
/home/didula/BVLOAM_ws/src/visual_odometry/src/image_util.cpp:59:104: error: ‘scoreType’ was not declared in this scope
detector = cv::ORB::create(num_features, scaleFactor, nlevels, edgeThreshold, firstLevel, WTA_K, scoreType

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: search in opencv documentation for ORB, then browse for those "score types"

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `cv2.FastFeatureDetector_create()` , if yes try to change it to `fast = cv2.FastFeatureDetector()`

Comment: this question looks like C++, not Python